Apps are being pushed under the notch
I just upgraded the my macos on my computer from Monterey to Sonoma and realized that the notch is now pushing windows down when resized on the notch area.
I always hide the menu bar and back when I was using Monterey the top of windows use to get under the notch with no problems, but now whenever I try to drag the windows to the top of the screen they are pushed down under the notch like this:

I've double check firefox options in finder, and "Scale to fit below built-in camera." option is on.

Any ideas of what could be causing this?

Are you saying that you used to be able to drag a window into the area where the menubar (and notch) usually is? I've never seen/heard of that behaviour, and certainly can't replicate it in either Window or Full Screen mode.

Yes I was, but in Monterey. I may have edited some config using "defaults", but I don't remember which using something like I was using Monterey since 2021, and I've regretted the decision to update it after this issue. I use the spectacle app, and when I "maximized" windows they used to use the entire screen
